# what will happen if server reach max threads

Tags: http, web, server

When i study network and server knowledge. I'm curious about one question

`Is user requests and server threads a one on one map?`

`What if there are 1001 users requests simutaniously and linux server has max threads as 1000`?

I don't know how to do experiments for this. So here is my specific question

`if a web server set its max threads as 1000, and there are 1001 users who are downloading a 5GB file. what will happen to the last user? wait and timeout? or just hang there until user send data to him`

Comment: Not really. A user can have multiple comcurrent connections to the server. However most httpds will allow you to specify a max per client connection limit as well on top of the global server connection limit.

Comment: @Sherif well, you can treat my question as "4 concurrent connections are 4 users". What i really want to know is what will happen if connections are more than web server max threads

Comment: Then typically the server will put the excess connections in a wait queue until more connections free up. Of course this depends on the httpd but if said queue is also exceeded or one is not available then the server should return a 503 http error code.